# Run a program and log to both screen and file in real time

Tags: windows-10, powershell, python

I've written a very simple python program (in reality my program is a lot more complex):

```
from time import sleep
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    sleep(1)
```

to print the digits 0-9, 1 each second over 10 seconds. I've saved it as `TestShell.py`

I can run it in powershell using

```
python .\TestShell.py
```

which outputs correctly, 1 digit each second. However I'd also like to store the output in a log file. I expected to use the `Tee-Object` for this

```
python .\TestShell.py | Tee-Object -FilePath .\fileLog.txt
```

which takes the log file as one parameter, and implicitly writes to console without a 2nd parameter. However now, no output is printed until the entire program is run. That is, I see nothing for 10 seconds, then the numbers 0-9 all at once.

**Is there any way to run a (python) file, outputting to the terminal and a log file in real time?**

Comment: Honestly, I would add the logging in the script itself.

Comment: @LPChip I thought about that, but in the real situation, most of the program output comes from a library I reference - I don't want to have to look inside it to change the logging. Even if I overload the default logger with a custom one, I have no way of guaranteeing the library isn't doing that too. So I really need a generic approach that monitors stdout and copies it to a file. I thought that was exactly what `tee` would do - maybe some different parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Well one approach can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/182537)

This is to use the -u switch to change the buffering mode of python itself, giving

```
python -u .\TestShell.py | Tee-Object -FilePath .\fileLog.txt
```

But that isn't a solution for all languages

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the PowerShell `Tee-Object` doesn't flush the output stream,
but only waits for the source to do that, so you get the output at the end of the
operation. This is by design.

Use this syntax instead to write the output line-by-line :

```
python .\TestShell.py | ForEach-Object { Write-Host $_; $_} | Set-Content .\fileLog.txt
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working - both the log and the terminal are only written to at the end of the execution :/ PS I assume that trailing `"` is a typo

Comment: Is this an answer that is in the context to [the original poster’s self answer](https://superuser.com/a/1376244/167207)?

Comment: Should be working. Strange.