# Save the output of a console app

Tags: windows

For far too long I'm trying to do something basic: save the output of a console app to a file in real time.
So far, I tried:

1. cygwin's tee: it suppresses ctrl+c.
2. powershell tee: doesn't auto-flush. This suggestion (for-each) doesn't auto-flush as well:
   [Run a program and log to both screen and file in real time](https://superuser.com/questions/1376241/run-a-program-and-log-to-both-screen-and-file-in-real-time)

To reiterate: I simply want to save the output to a log file without changing any aspect or behavior of the program. Not sure why it's not the default behavior of tee, much less why it doesn't have such an option.

---

Not to mention the other issues (encoding, red comments) that I resolved using powershell:

`pwsh -Command "$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{'Out-File:Encoding' = 'utf8'}; python run2.py 2>&1 | % ToString | Tee-Object _log.ans"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796476/displaying-windows-command-prompt-output-and-redirecting-it-to-a-file

Comment: Something specific that I haven't tried?

Comment: Do not use PowerShell. PowerShell does not offer sane handling of program input and output.

Answer (score 0):

Ridiculous; here `tee.py`:

```
import os, sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print( "Usage: ... | python", os.path.basename( sys.argv[0] ), "<log_file>" )
    sys.exit()
     
fname = sys.argv[1]

f = open( fname, 'w' )

while 1:
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if ch == '': # EOF
        break

    print( ch, end = '' )
    sys.stdout.flush()
    
    f.write( ch )
    f.flush()
```